# ¿Utilidad de la función lambda en Python?

Tags: python, lambda

Siguiendo la explicación de [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp), las funciones lambda son funciones anónimas que pueden usarse al interno de otras funciones. Creo no comprender a fondo su utilidad y uso a pesar de los numerosos ejemplos de la página.

A continuación expongo mis dudas:

**En el siguiente ejemplo, ¿en donde se declara el valor de la variable a?**

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n

mytripler = myfunc(3)

print(mytripler(11))
```

> Si `mytripler()` es la lambda ya no me parece tan anónima.

**¿Porqué usar lambda si se puede hacer lo siguiente?**

```
def myfunc(a, n):
  return a * n 

print(myfunc(3, 11))
```

**Cuando se dice que son funciones anónimas ¿se refiere a que son funciones que no tienen un nombre por el cual ser llamadas a su ejecución de esta manera `MiFuncion()`?**

Comment: "¿Porqué usar lambda si se puede hacer lo siguiente?" Porque lambda es más corto de escribir y lo tienes a la vista donde la ocupas. La función, en cambio, está definida en otra parte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las funciones lambda no son un concepto exclusivo de Python. Son típicas de la *programación funcional*, en la que es habitual que pases funciones como parámetro a otras funciones, o que devuelvas una función como resultado de invocar a otra función.

Si bien el concepto de retornar una función es extraño, y sus campos de aplicación podrían considerarse "avanzados" (decoradores, closures, incluso la posibilidad de evitar por completo la OOP y permitir mantener estado en variables de funciones en vez de en atributos de objetos), el concepto de pasar una función como parámetro es más fácil de comprender.

Por ejemplo, imagina que quieres hacer una función que cronometre cuánto tarda en ejecutarse otra función que recibe como parámetro (y por simplificar vamos a suponer que la función que recibe como parámetro no tiene parámetros). Entonces sería algo así:

```
import time
def cronometra(funcion_a_cronometrar):
  antes = time.time()
  resultado = funcion_a_cronometrar()
  despues = time.time()
  print("Ha tardado", despues-antes)
  return resultado  # Retornamos el resultado que originalmente devolvía la función
```

Ahora podemos usarla para cronometrar cualquier función "normal" con nombre, como por ejemplo:

```
def sumar_100_numeros():
  total = 0
  for n in range(100):
     total += n
  return total


cronometra(sumar_100_numeros)
```

Observa un detalle **muy importante**. A la función `cronometra()` le estamos pasando *el nombre* de la función a cronometrar. Un error típico sería escribir `cronometra(sumar_100_numeros())`. Esto estaría mal porque en este caso estaríamos llamando a `sumar_100_numeros()` *antes*, para pasar después el resultado a `cronometra()`. Esto daría un error, ya que ese resultado sería un entero, y no una función, por lo que cuando `cronometra` intente llamar `funcion_a_cronometrar()` rompería, ya que un entero no puede ser invocado.

En programación funcional es común esto de pasar funciones como parámetros de otras funciones. En la propia biblioteca estándar Python tienes las funciones `sorted()`, `max()` o `min()` que admiten un parámetro llamado `key` que sería la función que debe usarse sobre cada elemento de la lista a ordenar, antes de ordenarla. Internamente `sorted()` llamará a esa función para cada elemento de la lista, y usará el resultado de esa llamada para comparar entre sí los elementos.

Esto nos permite por ejemplo ordenar una lista de tuplas por su segundo elemento:

```
lista = [(2, 0), (1, 100), (200, 1)]

# Escribimos una función que recibe un elemento de la lista
# y retorna el segundo valor de la tupla
def segundo_valor_tupla(tupla):
   return tupla[1]

# Usamos esa función para ordenar
print(sorted(lista, key=segundo_valor_tupla))
```

Resultado:

```
[(2, 0), (200, 1), (1, 100)]
```

Hasta ahora hemos hablado de funciones como parámetros y las lambda no han aparecido por ningún sitio. ¿Cuándo es útil una lambda?

La respuesta es: cuando la función que voy a definir no es aprovechable en ninguna otra parte del código, y sólo la defino para ese caso particular.

En ese caso la función no necesita nombre porque se va a recibir como parámetro, y el parámetro ya tiene nombre (por ejemplo `key` en el caso de `sorted()`, o `funcion_a_cronometrar` en nuestro primer ejemplo). Es a través del nombre del parámetro como invocaremos la función. Su "verdadero" nombre es irrelevante.

En ese caso puedo usar una función lambda. No obstante en Python las funciones lambda son bastante especiales. En cualquier otro lenguaje una lambda podría tener condicionales, bucles, etc... Su única característica sería que no tienen nombre, y que se asignan a un parámetro (o se retornan como resultado). En cambio en python no es posible escribir el código de la función en el lugar en que iría el parámetro debido a que **python no tiene llaves**, y por tanto no podemos usar estructuras de control "en línea". Por ello las lambda de python están muy limitadas y pueden ser solamente una expresión.

```
lambda parametros: expresion
```

equivaldría a la función

```
def _anonima_(parametros):
   return expresion
```

De este modo podríamos reescribir nuestro ejemplo de ordenación con una lambda así:

```
print(sorted(lista, key=lambda tupla: tupla[1]))
```

### Otro ejemplo de uso

Otro ejemplo sería para realizar rellenado *parcial* de parámetros, cosa que se entenderá con el primer ejemplo que puse antes, el de la función que cronometraba otra función.

En aquél ejemplo, la función `cronometra()` se limita a llamar `funcion_a_cronometrar()` sin argumentos, lo que venía bien para cronometrar `sumar_100_numeros`, pero ¿y si quiero cronometrar, sin cambiar la función `cronometra()`, una función que reciba parámetros, como por ejemplo:

```
def sumar_m_numeros(m):
  total = 0
  for n in range(m):
    total += n
  return total
```

En este caso no puedo hacer `cronometra(sumar_m_numeros)` porque no le estaría pasando ningún parámetro y daría error, pero tampoco `cronometra(sumar_m_numeros(1000))`, porque en este caso llamaría antes a la función y pasaría el resultado a `cronometra()`, en vez de pasarle la función.

La solución sería crear una función "tonta" que no reciba parámetros y que internamente invoque a `sumar_m_numeros(1000)`, y pasar esa función "tonta" a `cronometra()`.

Cambia "tonta" por lambda y ya lo tenemos:

```
cronometra(lambda: sumar_m_numeros(1000))
```

Párate a pensar un momento este ejemplo. Lo que estamos pasando a `cronometra()` no es el resultado de ejecutar `sumar_m_numeros(1000)`, sino **una función** (la lambda) que aún no ha sido ejecutada. Cuando `cronometra()` invoque `funcion_a_cronometrar()` estará invocando la lambda, y en ese momento, al ejecutar la lambda, se evaluará la expresión `sumar_m_numeros(1000)` invocandose por primera vez esta función.

Este patrón se ve a menudo cuando necesitamos pasarle a una función otra que no recibe parámetros, pero queremos ejecutar una que sí los recibe. Un lugar típico donde se ve esto es a la hora de asociar acciones a botones en una GUI como Tkinter.

Comment: Uff, ya quedó todo claro con los ejemplos que todos me dieron. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

#### ¿Qué es?

En Python, `lambda` es una forma de definir funciones anónimas, reciben y devuelven parámetros

Tiene la siguiente sintaxis

```py
lambda parámetros : expresión
```

---

#### Ejemplos

En el siguiente ejemplo, podemos devolver un número multiplicado con otro con una función `lambda`

```py
multiplyNumb = lambda n : n * 5
```

El ejemplo anterior es equivalente a definir una función de la siguiente manera

```py
def multiplyNumb(n):
    return n * 5
```

Pero, hay casos específicos en los que podemos devolver una función

```py
def multiplyNumb(n):
    return lambda a : a * n
```

En este caso `multiplyNumb` devuelve una **función**, entonces podríamos hacer lo siguiente

```py
firstNumb = multiplyNumb(2)
```

En este caso, tenemos una función almacenada en `firstNumb`, pues la función principal nos devuelve una función *lambda*, el valor de `firstNuumb` será

```py
lambda a : a * 2
```

El 2 porque le dimos como parámetro "2" a la primera función, entonces `n` se reemplaza con 2

Entonces, solo nos queda llamar a la función para definir el valor de `a`

Para definirlo simplemente llamamos de nuevo a la función, sabiendo que recibirá un parámetro el cual será el valor de `a`

```py
firstNumb(20)
```

El resultado finalmente será 40, pues hemos llamado a la función *lambda* y le hemos dado *20* para que lo interprete con el valor de `a`, entonces nos devuelve el 2 que teníamos multiplicado con el parámetro que le dimos

---

#### ¿Por qué usar `lambda`?

Hay casos específicos en los que tenemos que devolver una función, si no es tu caso, con el ejemplo que pusiste bastaría

```py
def myfunc(a, n):
  return a * n 

print(myfunc(3, 11))
```

Pero, si tenemos que devolver una función específicamente, se usa `lambda`

```py
def sayHello(firstName):
    return lambda lastName : "Hola " + firstName + " " + lastName

sayHelloFstPart = sayHello("John")
print(sayHelloFstPart("Doe"))
```

Resultado

```
Hola John Doe
```

---

> Cuando se dice que son funciones anónimas ¿se refiere a que son funciones que no tienen un nombre por el cual ser llamadas a su ejecución de esta manera MiFuncion()?

Se dice que son funciones anónimas porque no tienen un nombre por el cual ser llamado, son devueltas por una función o asignadas a una variable

```py
(lambda a : 5 * a)(5)
```

En el ejemplo anterior, se define una función `lambda` y se la llama, si no se le asigna un nombre, no se podrá llamar

> Los paréntesis para que `(5)` no sea considerado como parte de la función `lambda`

Entonces definimos la función así

```py
(lambda a : 5 * a)
```

Y le añadimos paréntesis para llamar a la función

```py
(lambda a : 5 * a)(5)
```

Devolverá `25`, pues estamos llamando a la función pasándome "5" como parámetro

Comment: Excelente respuesta, me aclaraste muchas dudas. Aún sigo sin entender en qué caso necesitaría devolver una función, ya que contamos con objetos que pueden tener métodos como parámetros y no logro imaginar un caso de uso práctico para lambda.

Answer (score 4):

El ejemplo de W3Schools es un caso de *[currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)*. Ciertamente puedes lograr la misma salida haciéndolo de la manera en que planteas tú, pero lo que (supongo) se quiere demostrar con el primer ejemplo es la posibilidad de aplicar técnicas de *functional programming* en Python.

Para esto último `lambda` ayuda bastante, en vista de que puede ser innecesario definir una función regular (usando `def` y dándole un nombre), cuando nuestro objetivo es obtener cosas tales como *[closures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-closures/)* o *currying*.

Pongamos un ejemplo para ver esto mejor, ya que ciertamente el ejemplo de W3Schools dice mucho y poco a la vez.

Imagina que tienes un programa en donde existe una clase `Person`, que cuenta con un atributo `age`, y constantemente te encuentras filtrando a los objetos personas de acuerdo a sus edades. Pudieses tener una función que implemente el currying y que te permita (al menos) los siguientes tres beneficios:

- Reutilizar el código responsable de hacer el filtrado (apegándote al principio *DRY*)
- Reducir la cantidad de parámetros de la función. Mientras menos argumentos una función posea, mejor. Citando a Robert (Uncle Bob) Martin (2008, p. 40):

> El número ideal de argumentos para una función, es cero (nyladic) [...] Los argumentos son difíciles. Ellos toman mucho poder conceptual. Esa es la razón por la cual eliminé la mayor cantidad de ellos...

- Permitir tener nombres claros y expresivos para cada función responsable de hacer cada cosa.

La implementación luciría de la siguiente manera:

```
def filter_older_than(age):
    return lambda iterable: [person for person in iterable if person.age > age]


filter_older_than_five = filter_older_than(5)
filter_adults = filter_older_than(18)
filter_elderly = filter_older_than(60)


person_list = [Person(35), Person(6), Person(16), Person(65)]

# En algún lugar de tu código:
filter_elderly(person_list)


# ... y en algún otro lugar de tu código:
filter_adults(person_list)
```

Como puedes observar, el uso de `lambda` hizo mucho más directa la implementación. Gracias a ello no tuvimos la necesidad de definir una función aparte cuya única intención es ser devuelta para permitir el *currying*.

Por supuesto que pudiésemos haber implementado el código de arriba con un paradigma Orientado a Objetos, teniendo una clase padre `Filtro` con el método `filtrar()`, que sirva como interfaz, y tener clases hijas que especialicen y sobreescriban ese método de acuerdo a cada caso.

¿Es válido? Por supuesto, pero  la implementación usado el paradigma funcional también lo es. Allí, en mi opinión, radica la belleza de este lenguaje: en la flexibilidad que provee.

---

**Otro uso común de `lambda`**

En mi experiencia, en donde más he visto el uso de las funciones anónimas es al momento de proveer *callables* (o invocables) para el parámetro `key` de las funciones *built-ins* de ordenamiento. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> persons_sorted_by_age = sorted(person_list, key=lambda person: person.age)
>>> persons_sorted_by_age
[Person(age=6), Person(age=16), Person(age=35), Person(age=65)]
```

Allí se aprecia una clara ventaja de contar con `lambda`, al poder definir y utilizar una función allí mismo donde se necesita.

<sub>Ojo, yo para este caso prefiero el uso de `operators.attrgetter`, pero igualmente el uso de `lambda` se encuentra profundamente extendido para este fin.</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias por los ejemplos y referencias a la documentación.